# problem with FullCalendar Events...events brought from the DB collide with the ones added with addEvent

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

The title describes the problem.

When the user makes a selection in FullCalendar, a dialogue appears with title, start, end data ...upon clicking add submit button the following happens:

- ajax call to the db to add the event
- and call to calendar.addEvent

Here is some code to demo the above:

```
 if($('#new_appt_data').valid())
 {
         $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "events.php",
              dataType:"json",
              data:{"insert":true,"title":title,"start":fromDtime,"end":toDtime,"services":servicestatus,"staff":staffstatus,"origin":'backend',"packagetype":pack},
              success:function(data){
               var eventData = {id:data,title: title,origin:'backend', start:fromcal, end:endcal,services: servicestatus,staff:staffstatus};
                            calendar.addEvent(eventData);
                            $("#new_appt" ).dialog( "close" );
                          
                   },
              error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                          { 
                              $('#err_msg_new_appt').text('problem') 
                          } 

                });
```

Above you can see also non-standard event object fields...such as origin.

On the success callback I use addEvent to add the event to the Cal.

And now the problem:
This is an image when the event is added to the Cal..the week is 19-25 Apr.(sorry for the Greek)
[image: when event added]

Imagine now going  1 week ahead and the returning to the initial week(that the event was added...namely 19-25Apr) ... here is the image:
[image]

You see the same event appearing twice. It seems that the one event was the event added with addEvent FC method and the other comes as JSON from the database.

Why does this happen? Is there something wrong with my code (mainly from a logic point of view), or is it a FC bug?

I must also add that refreshing solves the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution after all...addEvent takes as an optional argument an eventsource object ID...by using that the cache is cleared before fetching the events from the DB.
Previousloy I had to set an event source object inside an eventsource array.